# find best approach to recognize list of sequence word in sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I have two list of words that I would like to find in a sentence based on a sequence. I would like to check is it possible to use "regular expression" or I should use check the sentence by if condition?

```
n_ali = set(['ali','aliasghar'])
n_leyla = set(['leyla','lili',leila])
positive_adj = set(['good','nice','handsome'])
negative_adj = set(['bad','hate','lousy'])


Sentence = "aliasghar is nice man. ali is handsome man of my life. lili has so many bad attitude who is next to my friend. "
```

I would like to find any pattern as below:

- n_ali +  positive_adj
- n_ali +  negative_adj
- n_leyla +  positive_adj
- n_leyla +  negative_adj

I am using python 3.5 in VS2015 and I am new in NLTK. I know how to create a "regular expression" for check a single word but I am not sure what is the best approach for list of similar names. kindly help me and suggest me what is the best way to implement this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider removing stopwords.

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
>>> words = [word for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) if word not in stopwords.words('english')]
>>> words
['aliasghar', 'nice', 'man', '.', 'ali', 'handsome', 'man', 'life', '.', 'lili', 'many', 'bad', 'attitude', 'next', 'friend', '.']
```

Alright, now you have the data like you want it (mostly). Let's use simple looping to store the results in pairs for `ali` and `leila` separately.

```
>>> ali_adj = []
>>> leila_adj = []
>>> for i, word in enumerate(words[:-1]):
...     if word in n_ali and (words[i+1] in positive_adj.union(negative_adj)):
...             ali_adj.append((word, words[i+1]))
...     if word in n_leyla and (words[i+1] in positive_adj.union(negative_adj)):
...             leila_adj.append((word, words[i+1]))
... 
>>> 
>>> ali_adj
[('aliasghar', 'nice'), ('ali', 'handsome')]
>>> leila_adj
[]
```

Note that we could not find any adjectives to describe `leila` because "many" isn't a stopword. You may have to do this type of cleaning of the sentence manually.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. it is solving 70% of my problem. in this example if you observe there is a issue. since you used words[i+1] only if adj come after name this pattern can recognize it. [ 'lili', 'many', 'bad',]  for instance for lili case it can not recognize lili and bad. do you recommend me extend this pattern for other cases? it will not decrease analysis speed? or we should remove many also?

Comment: I'm not sure how many words like "many" you'll have to remove in a large document, so I would say you go ahead with checking for adjectives 2 places ahead also (instead of just 1).

Comment: then we don't face with out of index exception? shall I control it with try and catch?